# If $x^*Ax=x^*Bx$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, then $A=B.$

Tags: linear-algebra

For $A=[a_{ij}], B=[b_{ij}] \in M_n(\mathbb{C}),$ I want to show that if $x^*Ax=x^*Bx$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, then $A=B.$

I know that if $x=e_i$, (where $e_i$ is the vector with 1 in the $ith$ entry and 0 elsewhere), we have $e_i^*Ae_i=e_i^*Be_i \implies a_{ii}=b_{ii}$. Hence, diagonal entries of $A$ and $B$ are equal. 
But how do I show that $a_{ij}=b_{ij}$ for $i \neq j?$ It was hinted that $a_{ij}$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors of the form $x^*Ax$ where the coefficients are from $\mathbb{C}$ (hence why the statement isn't true for $\mathbb{R}$). I have no idea how to find the right coefficients and each $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ that will work. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $B=0$.

Take $x = e_i + i e_j$ with $i$ the imaginary unit. Then
$$
x^*Ax = (e_i - ie_j)^TA(e_i+ie_j) = a_{ii}+a_{jj} + i(-a_{ji}+a_{ij}) =0.
$$
Setting $x= e_i + e_j$ gives
$$
x^*Ax = (e_i +e_j)^TA(e_i+e_j) = a_{ii}+a_{jj} + a_{ji}+a_{ij} =0.
$$
Since you already know $a_{ii}=a_{jj}=0$, both equations imply $a_{ij}=0$ and $a_{ji}=0$. So $A=0$.

Comment: Why did you assume that $B=0?$

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to: $x^*(A-B)x=0$ implies $A-B=0$. So we can substitute $A$ by $A-B$ and $B$ by $0$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.